# Intel Atom D2500, 64-bit mode

Tags: cpu, 64-bit, intel-atom, 32-vs-64-bit

I have an Intel Atom D2500 processor which the [spec site](http://ark.intel.com/products/59682/Intel-Atom-Processor-D2500-1M-Cache-1_86-GHz) claims it supports a 64-bit instruction set. However, cpuinfo shows this:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo | egrep "(processor|flags|address)"
processor       : 0
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36  clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts  nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl tm2 ssse3 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm arat
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
processor       : 1
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36  clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts  nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl tm2 ssse3 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm arat
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
```

Does anyone know any way to enable the `lm` flag in the processor? So I can use a 64-bit kernel?

Comment: What motherboard to you have?

Answer (score 1):

You can really easily test this with any Live 64bit Linux distro. I can confirm that Linux Mint 15 64bit runs on D2500, but has really bad GPU artefact issues.

Comment: Well, it looks like it will depend on the motherboard manufacturer, so my MB did not supported long mode, and that why it did not work.

Comment: Precisely. For many features to work it needs support at all levels. Your CPU supports it, but motherboard (firmware) and OS also need to support it.